# Can I use a BC338 in this application?

Tags: transistors, npn, transmitter, frequency-modulation

I want to build this FM transmitter that runs on 1.5-3V.

I've got 2 questions so far:

1. Can I use a 2N2222A NPN in this application? (I think I can but want to double check.)
2. How can I calculate (or measure) the transmission frequency?

[image: Circuit]

P.S. L will be 6 turns on 1/2" dia. with 3/4" length.

Comment: You should use a crystal. Then you won't be calculating the transmission frequency. You'll be using the one stamped on the crystal.

Comment: @jonk How would you suggest doing this? Is it possible to use a crystal in this current circuit or would it be better to re-design the entire thing?

Comment: Crystals were a huge deal for radio stations going as far back [WEAF](http://www.theradiohistorian.org/weaf/weaf.html), which was the first commercial radio station to use one in 1926. Within just a few years, all commercial radio stations used them. For FM, these became a big deal for the US just prior to getting into WW II and by 1944 just about everyone was in the business making the darned things. For ground troops, the [FT-243 case](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/radio/xtal/index.htm) was used a lot. The web must be packed with schematics by now. Have you looked?

Comment: When looking around for a schematic that uses a crystal, be aware that modern crystals are ... feeble. Those old FT-243s would take significant currents and not move from their fabrication frequency. Modern crystals would heat up using an old circuit and would, at best, drift around as they heated. At worst, they'd just break. So you either need a modern circuit for FM or else need to find someone selling a crystal of the size similar to the FT-243 crystals. (Which can withstand a lot.) We are 'cheap' now. So mostly just thin, flimsy crystals today. I should've bought boxes of the FT-243. ;)

Comment: Look for circuits using the 3rd harmonic of the crystal -- these are called "overtone" transmitters -- if you want something simple. There are also buckets of ICs to help out, too, these days. But they have complicated datasheets. So I won't recommend any of those. A quick 'google' found [this site](http://circuit-zone.com/index.php?cat=fm_transmitters) which has lots of links to various types of FM transmitters. Might be worth a look-see.

Comment: Thanks a heap for all the help, I don't know if this is just an issue with my browser, but the site you linked seems to not have any actual schematics, however i've found a video that details the schematic and build: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FauFCfy4jeM

Comment: If you click the ***titles*** it will take you to web pages, I believe. For example, I just selected one of them that took me [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FauFCfy4jeM). There's a schematic in the description (I now see.) It is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7b9b3JCCJGzvksZSb4ma5P-Z_mnezbi/view). So long as you are dealing with low power transmitters, the modern crystals won't "burn out" from abuse from such direct, simple transmitter circuits. But if you want to increase the transmitted power much, I wouldn't count on them surviving long.

Comment: Simulate your circuit before building it.

Comment: TL/DR : forget the crystal. Simply dropping a crystal into that oscillator may not allow enough frequency deviation without other pretty major changes. It is possible to pull a crystal by about 100ppm, so 10kHz deviation is possible, which will make for a pretty quiet FM transmitter (standard is 75kHz at full modulation) but I doubt that circuit can get anywhere close to that.

Comment: That looks like an AM circuitry, not FM.

Answer (score 1):

> [...]can I use a 2N2222A NPN in this application (I think I can but
> want to double check)? And how can I calculate (or measure) the
> transmission frequency?

2N2222A should have enough gain at 100 MHz to oscillate. Probably better than BC338, whose gain is feeble at this frequency.

Folks who build these minimalist circuits often have no test equipment that can measure high frequency **amplitude** or **frequency**.
The most obvious way to measure frequency uses a *frequency counter*. A small sensing loop of a turn or two connects to the counter's input via a coaxial cable. The sensing loop is placed near the inductor. It need not make any physical connection to the circuit.

If you're lucky, the circuit will oscillate somewhere within the FM broadcast band. If so, you can scan an FM radio through its frequency range while this circuit operates nearby. Disturbing the inductor with a finger should disturb the oscillator's frequency.

It is nearly impossible to calculate with decent accuracy the oscillating frequency. Construction of the inductor, circuit wiring, and component tolerances are simply too variable. Since the antenna adds some capacitance, its length affects frequency as well. The variable capacitor in parallel with the inductor is meant to adjust oscillator frequency...more capacitance yields a lower frequency.

Some constructors try to build this on a no-solder proto-board - a no-no at these high frequencies. One of the better methods starts with a continuous-plane unetched copper circuit board. One usually chooses to make the copper area **ground**. In this case, only three components would be considered "grounded", while eight components connect to **Vcc**.
 It would make more sense to use the copper area for **Vcc** to which eight components would have one end soldered directly. All other soldered connections would be flying ones above the board (with short leads). Its ugly, but works surprisingly well when you're only building one unit.